# How do we make spinners like in Web?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I just need a spinner which is like in Web. Is is possible to do? I've searching for below sample image. I just googling that, but i got only spinners like iPhone. How to do like in below image? Anyone guide me?

[image: Spinner]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First link on a google search for custom spinner... http://www.gersic.com/blog.php?id=57

Answer (score 0):

See the tutorial here: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html

Comment: What's in there? I've also referred that.

Comment: I know how to create a spinners in android dude. But, i need an bit of idea to create like that one.